# Using an outside function "swap" to perform the swap step of bubblesort, but with an array of Structs in c?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am currently writing a program that takes user inputted (input?) names and scores, for which the information goes in a struct student, containing a char array names, and int score.

So this bubblesort is comparing strings in the struct, but I have to use an outside function named swap to move the information around, which is where I am lost.

so far I have this:

```
void bubbleSort(struct namscores ns, int n){
          int i, j;
          for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                for(j=0; j < n - i - 1; j++){
                      if(strcmp(ns[j].name,ns[j+1].name)>0){
                              //swap here
                      }
                }
          }        
}
```

The struct was created first as so:

```
struct namscores {
      char name[15];
      int scores;
}
```

So, I just don't understand how swap in this situation works. I would swap the elements of the structs? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. I though about sending both structs,

```
r[j] and r[j+1]
```

to the swap function, but that doesn't seem correct either?

Comment: You don't show the swap function. It could be implemented in different ways. Btw the first parameter should be a pointer

Comment: @Artefacto I haven't written a swap yet. I didn't quite know how to start it.

Comment: You already have a problem before even getting to the body of your function.  Your prototype shows you passing a single structure.  You can't sort a single structure.  There's only one of them.  Did you intend for it to be a pointer instead?  Normally you would pass a pointer so that you can index into it to access individual elements of an array.  In your case, `ns[j]` will give an error since you can't index into a scalar object.

Comment: @TomKarzes So thats what  was talking about. I should do ```struct namscores* ns?``` ? Im not sure how the syntax looks with there being 3 names. Would it be ``` struct namscore ns```?

Comment: @NameNotFound `struct namscores *ns` would declare `ns` to be a pointer to a `struct namscores`, which seems to be what you need. You might want to look for a tutorial on arrays and pointers so you can master the basics before attempting something like this.

Comment: @TomKarzes understood, unfortunately my professor did not get too much into the basics before telling us to figure this out on our own. That makes sense though, and for passing this, once again excuse my ignorance, it would be passed with an &, correct? So ``` bubbleSort(&namscores, num) ``` ?

Comment: How would you swap two integers?  (Hint: pointers!)  That's basically how you swap two structures too.

Comment: @NameNotFound No, you would only use `&namescores` if you were passing the address of a *single* structure.  If you have an array, just passing the array name will convert it to a pointer.  And if you have a pointer, then just pass the pointer.

Comment: @TomKarzes that makes a lot more sense, thank you!

Comment: Please double check that you are really using an array of structs. You clearly say so, I admit. I ask you to double check because sorting an array of compound datatypes (most importantly structs) is usually avoided. That is the reason why I suspect that you might actually be using an array of pointers to structs. I.e. `struct something* Array[N];` instead of `struct something Array[N];`. I recommend to double check this, because those are different things, one is more widely spread and what you need to do for sorting is quite different and with array of pointers much easier.